# How to get all data of array of ids in one query in graphql?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

My query for Roster -

```
query GetRoster(
  $startDate: DateTime!
  $endDate: DateTime!
  $wardId: String!
  $rosterTypeId: String!
) {
  roster: getRoster(
    roster: {
      startDate: $startDate
      endDate: $endDate
      wardId: $wardId
      rosterTypeId: $rosterTypeId
    }
  ) {
    _id
    duties {
      _id
      allocation {
        _id
        email
        fullName
      }
      isCancelled
    }
    cancelledDuties {
      _id
      allocation {
        _id
        fullName
        email
      }
    }
    shiftTemplate {
      _id
      name
      startTime {
        hour
        minute
      }
      duration {
        hour
        minute
      }
      requirements {
        minimumStrength
        requiredProcedures {
          procedure {
            _id
            name
          }
        }
        requiredRoles {
          hospitalRoleType {
            _id
            hospitalRoleType {
              title
            }
          }
          minimumAssignments
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This takes single wardId and returns roster of only that wardId.
But I have an array of wards which contains wardIds but I don't want to query getRoster for each wardIds instead is there any method to get rosters for all wards of wards array by wardId in one query ?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works. i am not a professional with graphql. I only use it in combination with strapi and node.js, but maybe it can help you on your way.

I used a filter to filter all rosters for rosters with a wardId in the $wardIds array. The other filters are for the other filter data you wanted to filter on.

I use google translate, so sorry if there are any spelling or grammar mistakes.

```
query GetRoster(
  $startDate: DateTime!
  $endDate: DateTime!
  $wardIds: [ID!] 
  $rosterTypeId: String!
) {
  rosters(
    filters: {
      and: [
        { wardId: { in: $wardIds } } 
        { startDate: { eq: $startDate } } 
        { endDate: { eq: $endDate } } 
        { rosterTypeId: { eq: $rosterTypeId } } 
      ]
    }
  ) {
    _id
    duties {
      _id
      allocation {
        _id
        email
        fullName
      }
      isCancelled
    }
    cancelledDuties {
      _id
      allocation {
        _id
        fullName
        email
      }
    }
    shiftTemplate {
      _id
      name
      startTime {
        hour
        minute
      }
      duration {
        hour
        minute
      }
      requirements {
        minimumStrength
        requiredProcedures {
          procedure {
            _id
            name
          }
        }
        requiredRoles {
          hospitalRoleType {
            _id
            hospitalRoleType {
              title
            }
          }
          minimumAssignments
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```